# How to extract accelerometer column and the data between the words "start" and "stop" from a csv and write into new csv file

Tags: python, csv

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib import style 

path= r'C:\Users\npatel\Documents\Coremotion Data\MotionData\data_file.csv'
datafile = open(path)
data = open(path,'r')

reader = path.reader(datafile)
interestingrows=[row for idx, row in enumerate(reader) if idx in 
(start,stop)]

new_path = r'C:\Users\npatel\Documents\Coremotion 
Data\MotionData\new_data.csv'
new_data = open(new_path,'w')
title = 'trial'
new_data.write(title)
print(title)
new_data.write(data)
print(data)
```

Error: 'str' object has no attribute 'reader'

I am new to python , so just learnt to read and write files but how can I extract the data between the keywords "start" and "stop" and save it to a new file? There are more than 10 columns but I want to extract only 4 columns with specific title.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). `reader` is a method of the `csv` package, not of a string.  YOu open the file and pass the file handle to `csv.reader`.  In your case, something like

```
csv_reader = csv.reader(datafile)
```

I'm not sure what you're planning to do with `path`, the second `open` on your file.  You open it in "read" mode, but later use that as data to write out.

Comment: That was just practice. I want to extract the data between two keywords and then write that into a new file.

Comment: Extracting data between two keywords is  well-documented problem on Stack Overflow and elsewhere.